# RE: Query Help to pull from main DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

i created a query to select from the master audience DE that do not exist in the CRM file. However, when i go to check the DE only subscription status pulls in... do i have something incorrect?

```
Select s.EmailAddress, s.Subscription_Status, s.SubscriberKey
From Chicos_Master_Audience as s
Where Not Exists(Select SubscriberKey
From chs_crm_emails as c where s.SubscriberKey = c.Subscriber_Key)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Select s.EmailAddress, s.Subscription_Status, s.SubscriberKey
From Chicos_Master_Audience as s
Where a.Subscriber_Key NOT IN (Select distinct(SubscriberKey) 
From chs_crm_emails)
```